# Multiple OSX users to multiple spaces

Tags: macos, virtual-desktop, osx-spaces, multiple-users

IS there a way to have multiple users on OSX active at the same time, and switch between them by swiping to go between spaces, rather than using "fast user switching"?

I want to do this, because I like to keep certain different clients/employers as different desktops (and have my managed applications isolated), but sometimes need to switch between user accounts quickly. This would be much easier if I could use the spaces gesture instead of the fast user switching (which requires accessing a menu, and entering a password, every single time).

Thanks,

Kevin N.

Comment: I hoping something like this will be possible. Makes for a much faster user switching.

Comment: I haven't found a way yet.